# How to depict your name on your iPhone's lock screen?

Tags: iphone, screen-lock, ios

Before upgrading to iOS 7 from iOS 6, I had the wallpaper of my iPhone 4S lock screen show my name, address, and email address. Just in case somebody found my phone and was willing to see it returned.

After upgrading to iOS 7, I noticed that any notifications to the lock screen will blur the text to practical invisibility, even if I manoeuvre the text on the wallpaper right in between the top line and the time. (Also, but not relevant to the question, the text placed there moves quite a bit around if you tilt the phone.)

In iOS 7, is there a way to leave some details to be easily<sup>1</sup> found by the finder of the locked phone? (And I do not mean writing/scratching on the phone or a sticker. I actually came from the earlier sticker-on-the-back solution.)

<sup><sup>1</sup>The finder might figure out that you can remove the notification, but, even if aware of the possibility, that might not be the obvious thing to do at all.</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you very well explained, the notifications will blur any image. So, the options are:

1. Not to show any notification on the lock screen
2. To depend on the [Find my iPhone service](https://www.apple.com/icloud/find-my-iphone.html) from Apple.

I personally would not do #1, as I lose features from my phone. I have, however, activated the "Find my iPhone" service.

With this service, if your phone is lost, you can send messages to it (that will be displayed on the lock screen) and/or you can block the device and let the person only call a specific (alternative) number. This is called the "Lost Mode".

The only drawback, I see compared to your iOS 6 Wallpaper solution, is that you will have to go to a computer and access the [iCloud site](https://www.icloud.com/) to effectively enable one of those features.

Apple has added [Activation Lock](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5818) in iOS 7, that if enabled, even if stolen, your iPhone cannot be deleted or activated with another Apple ID. If the finding person/thief knows this, he will probably return it to you.